# Use part of string from column to calculate and populate another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a pandas dataframe which contains values like the following:

['3m5f Hcap', '6f Maiden', '7f Hcap', '2m6f Stks', '3m Hcap']

These refer to the length of horse races, so for example 3m5f (3 miles and 5 furlongs) is the equivalent to 29 furlongs.

I need to create a new column that converts the various race lengths to integers representing the total number of furlongs.

So the above would be

[29, 6, 7, 20, 24]

I'm not even sure where to start with this one, any ideas appreciated!

Comment: for starters its what 8 furlongs in a mile? also each observation is a list like that or thats simply you showing the values in a list?

Comment: yeah there are 8 furlongs in a mile. each value is a single cell in a dataframe column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not as savvy as @Psidom in `pandas` so here is another way of doing it:

```
def my_func(_data):
    val = _data.split(' ')[0]
    try:
        midx = val.index('m') - 1
    except ValueError:
        midx = None
    try:
        fidx = val.index('f') - 1
    except ValueError:
        fidx = None
    m = int(val[midx]) if midx != None else 0
    f = int(val[fidx]) if fidx != None else 0
    return m * 8 + f

df['furlong'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: my_func(x))

        data  furlong
0  3m5f Hcap       29
1  6f Maiden        6
2    7f Hcap        7
3  2m6f Stks       22
4    3m Hcap       24
```

And then timed against his answer:

```
time df['furlong'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: my_func(x))

CPU times: user 679 µs, sys: 123 µs, total: 802 µs
Wall time: 713 µs

def test(df):
    return (df.data.str.extract("(?:(?P<m>\d+)m)?(?:(?P<f>\d+)f)?", expand=False).fillna(0).astype(int).pipe(lambda df: df.m * 8 + df.f))

time test(df)

CPU times: user 3.37 ms, sys: 1.01 ms, total: 4.38 ms
Wall time: 3.76 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a data frame as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"dist": ['3m5f Hcap', '6f Maiden', '7f Hcap', '2m6f Stks', '3m Hcap']})

df
#   dist
#0  3m5f Hcap
#1  6f Maiden
#2  7f Hcap
#3  2m6f Stks
#4  3m Hcap
```

You can `extract` the *mile*(assume *m* means *mile*) and *furlongs* in separate columns and then convert them to *furlongs*:

```
(df.dist.str.extract("(?:(?P<m>\d+)m)?(?:(?P<f>\d+)f)?", expand=False)
 .fillna(0).astype(int).pipe(lambda df: df.m * 8 + df.f))

#0    29
#1     6
#2     7
#3    22
#4    24
#dtype: int64
```